# Bamboo - Octopus integration for CI/CD

Tags: .net, continuous-deployment, bamboo, octopus-deploy, octopus

I'm new to Octopus and trying to deploy my Windows service. I'm trying to integrate Bamboo and Octopus. In Bamboo, as of now I have added few tasks which builds the application and runs the test cases. Now I have to add new tasks to deploy the code. I'm following [this article](https://octopus.com/docs/api-and-integration/bamboo) to do that.

Now to add MSBuild executable, what I did is, go to the bamboo download folder->Bin-> open bamboo-capabilities.properties file and added this line at the end:

```
system.builder.command.MSBuild15=C:\\Program\ Files\ (x86)\\Microsoft\ Visual\ Studio\\2017\\BuildTools\\MSBuild\\15.0\\Bin\\MSBuild.exe.
```

So, in the Task, when I added Command, in Executable drop down list, `MSBuild15` is appearing, which I selected for building the application.

Now similarly, I want to add for Octopus as well.

As mentioned in the above link, in the second step `Create the package`, I have to add Octopus CLI. I'm not sure how to add it. Because I do not have `Add New Executable` link.  So I wanted to follow the same process I followed for MSBuild. I have added this line in the config file of Bamboo.

```
system.octopus.executable.Octopus15=C:\\OctoCLI\\Octo.exe
```

Then I clicked on New task -> select Octopus Deploy :Pack Package . Here I need to select Ocotopus CLI. But the above `Octopus15` is not displayed in the dropdown. So can anyone tell me if what I'm doing is wrong and what is the correct procedure.

Extra information: I have a server where Bamboo agent is installed and configured from there. I start Bamboo agent on the server manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to bring the octopus capabilities to the bamboo, we can add the Octopus add-ons.
To access the add-ons page from Bamboo, you can use the configuration icon in the top right corner.
In the addons you can search for Octopus Deploy Bamboo Plugin
[image: Screen Shot of Add On Screen]

After adding the Octopus add on, while adding a new task into the build tasks you will see the following options.
[image: Octopus task types]